# how to change my domain to point Amazon AWS EC2

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-ec2, dns-lookup

I have a domain in 1and1.com , I have been using it with hostgator hosting. Now I want it to point to my amazon aws ec2 instance. Here are the steps i have followed.

1. I logged into AWS and chose Rout 53
2. The I have created a Hosted Zone and gave my domain name. "example.com"
3. Then there were 4 Name servers.
4. I took them and logged into 1and1 control panel , And change my Name servers to this values.

ns-16.awsdns-02.com
ns-1329.awsdns-38.org
ns-675.awsdns-20.net
ns-2018.awsdns-60.co.uk

5. Now it is giving me a proxy error. :(

Can anyone please explain me, where it went wrong??
( My instance works fine, and Ihave associated an Elastic IPfor that too.. )

Comment: Did you add an A record in route 53?

Comment: A record?? What is that?I have no idea. :(

Comment: Set the A record and works  like a charm. Thanks man.. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need route 53 if your registrar is 1and1 .

You just have to change your records from your domain to point to your Elastic IP.

If you want to move to Route 53, you have to change your nameservers for your domain at 1and1 to Amazon's and repeat the top step.

Comment: Let's say my Elastic ip is 52.52.52.52 , What do I have to do now?? Ad dthis IPto the 1and 1 account??